# Exclude row if one of 2 flattened columns didn't return

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am joining against a view, in a stored procedure to try and return a record.

In one table I have something like this:

```
Measurement | MeasurementType | Date Performed
```

I need to plot `TireHeight` and `TireWidth`.

So I am flattening that table into one row.

I only want to return a row though if both `TireHeight` and `TireWidth` were measured on that date. I am not using the date performed for anything other than joining `TireWidth` and `TireHeight` together. I run a calculation on these 2 numbers for my chart point, and use `TireAge` for the other axis.

How can I exclude a result row if either `TireHeight` or `TireWidth` are not available?

Thanks!

Comment: how does your existing query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use an INNER JOIN to only return rows when they are present in both tables.  For example:

```
SELECT   th.DatePerformed
,        th.Measurement as TireHeight
,        tw.Measurement as TireWidth
FROM (
    SELECT DatePerformed, Measurement
    FROM   Measurements
    WHERE  MeasurementType = 'TireHeight'
) th
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DatePerformed, Measurement
    FROM   Measurements
    WHERE  MeasurementType = 'TireWidth'
) tw
ON tw.DatePerformed = th.DatePerformed
```